# Uncaught ReferenceError: MarkerWithLabel is not defined jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery, google-maps, google-maps-markers

I am using these two links to work with google map

```
<script src="https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?key=AIza...................&language=en&sensor=false&libraries=geometry,places&ext=.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdn.rawgit.com/googlemaps/v3-utility-library/master/markerwithlabel/src/markerwithlabel.js"></script>
```

And the later was not loading at all showing 404. So i searched and find another script to add to work with

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://google-maps-utility-library-v3.googlecode.com/svn/trunk/markerwithlabel/src/markerwithlabel.js"></script>
```

but this won't work either. Since I am working with jQuery so below link won't work with my project

```
<script src="https://unpkg.com/@googlemaps/markerwithlabel/dist/index.min.js"></script>

marker = new MarkerWithLabel({
  position: new google.maps.LatLng(locations[i][1], locations[i][2]),
  map: this.map,
  labelContent: j,
  labelAnchor: new google.maps.Point(15, 65),
  labelClass: "labels", // the CSS class for the label
  labelInBackground: false,
  id : Arr[i],
  zIndex:100,
  icon: myApp.pinSymbol(marker_color)
});
```

this is giving me error saying **Uncaught ReferenceError: MarkerWithLabel is not defined**

Comment: Your "updated" link also appears to give a 404 (for me).   Double check the network tab (which I assume you did to find the first one giving a 404).

Comment: The ("a") [MarkerWithLabel github page](https://github.com/googlemaps/js-markerwithlabel) suggests this link: https://unpkg.com/@googlemaps/markerwithlabel@1.2.2/dist/index.min.js  (no idea if it's the same "MarkerWithLabel")

Comment: Your third snippet seems to load MarkerWithLabel fine as it gives `google is not defined` which is *inside* MarkerWithLabel.   Please provide a *complete* [mcve] with all the relevant includes (might not be possible if you need an api key, don't include it)

Comment: Finally: the MarkerWithLabel examples all fail to work, so I suspect it's out of date with the current google map requirements.

Comment: @freedomn-m I stumbled upon that library a few days ago and the description just makes **no sense**: *The library creates and manages per-zoom-level clusters for large amounts of markers.* - so the library name is MarkerWithLabel but the description corresponds to MarkerClusterer...

Comment: @jpoehnelt if you are the maintainer of this library (and it seems you are), please advise / update the library description. Thanks.

Comment: The posted code "works" for me (when I fix the errors and add the missing pieces): [fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/geocodezip/Lt04xmz7/).  Not sure what this question has to do with jQuery.  Please provide a [mcve] that demonstrates your issue.

Answer (score 0):

The code has changed to create an instance of a marker (if you are importing their script into a web page using `<script src="...">`). See [the code in this example](https://googlemaps.github.io/js-markerwithlabel/examples/picturelabel.html) which is different than their [github example](https://github.com/googlemaps/js-markerwithlabel).

So, after you import Google Map API and then the MarkerWithLabel from the unpkg src, instead of this:

```js
marker = new MarkerWithLabel({
  ...
})
```

Use this:

```js
marker = new markerWithLabel.MarkerWithLabel({
   ...
});
```